# xparse SplitList parameter expansion

Tags: xparse

I need to split comma-separed string from variable (actually data file) for further procesing.

There is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}  
colA;  
A,B,C;  
\end{filecontents*}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunc}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }{\ProcessList{#1}{\func}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\func}{m}{\fbox{#1}}

\newcommand{\textA}{a,b,c}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt

(1) \myfunc{a,b,c}\\  % OK
(2) \myfunc{\textA}\\ % Wrong
(3) \expandafter\myfunc\expandafter{\textA}\\ % OK

\csvreader[
head to column names,
separator=semicolon
]{sample.csv}{}%
{
(4) \expandafter\myfunc\expandafter{\colA} % Wrong (how to correct?)
}
\end{document}
```

What is the correct way to expand argument in case (4) in the same way as (1) or (3)??

Thank you very much in advance for any help or suggestion!

Best regards,

Lubos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has not much to do with `xparse`, rather with the fact that `\csvreader` sets `\colA` to a macro containing what you're after, so it needs to be expanded twice.  One way is to do

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\myfunc
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\colA}
```

instead of only two `\expandafter`.

Comment: You are exactly right, thats work as expected! Thanks for explanation (and sorry for possible confusion). BTW: (just curious) any way to use any "shotcut" commands (and again sorry, I love TeX but I'm not Tex guru...)?

Comment: I would probably use `expl3`: for instance (between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`) one could do `(4) ~ \exp_args:Nf \myfunc { \colA }` to fully expand `\colA` on the left.  (Note I used `~` for the space after `(4)`.)

Comment: @LubošKejzlar You have already asked several questions here, and most of them seem to have reasonable answers. Please consider [to accept answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) if they worked for you (you can accept at most one answer per question) and/or to [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) them (you can upvote all answers that you appreciate). Maybe spare two minutes [to take the tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).